# OracleSolaris 11.2 and dual boot with Linux

Tags: solaris, dual-boot, opensolaris

I've read through different documents describing dual-boot configuration Solaris+Linux, however I'm still struggling with it.

I first installed Fedora12, and then OracleSolaris 11.2, which of course installed its own copy of grub2. Here is what partitions I have (reported by gparted):

```
Partition table GPT
/dev/sda1 rootFS ext4
/dev/sda2 linux-swap
/dev/sda4 bios_grub
/dev/sda3  solaris rpool
```

Now I want be able to boot into the linux from Solaris' grub menu, therefore I added in /rpool/boot/grub/custom.cfg:

```
menuitem "Fedora 12" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6e45cbca-b615-41e3-ab4e-e70271b0452c
    chainloader --force +1
}
```

Now I do see two menu items in solaris' grub menu, Oracle Solaris and Fedora12, but the latter fails to boot, saying "command chainload unknown".

What am I doing wrong, and how can I achieve dual boot?

**UPDATE** Could it be that Solaris doesn't have good support of ext4 partitions? For example, http://www.unix.com/solaris/225165-unable-mount-ext4-filesystem-created-ubuntu-solaris-11-a.html says so, but it dates to 2013.

**UPDATE2** It should be *chainloader* not *chainload* Also I added *search* command to find a partition with specific UUID (the same as defined in Fedora's grub menu), and assign it it root. But still I'm getting error when try to boot Fedora:

```
error: invalid signature
```

I suspect it doesn't see an actual boot record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the dual-boot. Actually I installed linux's grub in /dev/sda1, and *chainloader* was able to pick up fedora's boot; I slightly modified my */rpool/boot/grub/custom.cfg*:

```
menuitem "Fedora 12" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root=(hd0,gpt1)
    chainloader +1
    boot
}
```

It also helped carefully re-read the following article at oracle's blog https://blogs.oracle.com/Hartmut/entry/dual_boot_oracle_solaris_11

Comment: so are you booting both systems from Fedora GRUB or Solaris GRUB? Also, can you post the custom configuration you use to boot second OS? Thx.